# c++ wrap macro into a template class

Tags: c++, templates, macros

I have a macro which can't be changed and I need to wrap it into a template class that is not generated by another macro. The class should take the "name" field value as a template argument and provide a method redirecting to the function, which is defined by the macro.

Simplified example of the macro:

```
#define MACRO(name) \
std::string GetMacroValue##name() \
{ \
    std::string str##name(#name); \
    return str##name; \
} \
```

The pseudocode of the wrapper structure the way I see it:

```
template<[NAMEFIELD]>
class MacroWrapper
{
public:
    MacroWrapper() {}
    std::string getValue()
    {
        return GetMacroValue[NAMEFIELD]();
    }
private:
    MACRO([NAMEFIELD])
};
```

The result is like this:

```
MacroWrapper<[NAMEFIELD]> wrapper;
std::cout << wrapper.getValue(); // prints the [NAMEFIELD]
```

I use C++20, so I can use string literals in template arguments, but is it still possible to create such a wrapper?

Comment: Can't be done in the way requested: template instantiation happens four [translation phases](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) after preprocessing is done

Comment: You could probably write a new macro that generates a `MacroWrapper` specialization with a suitable method though.

Comment: Macros don't understand variables or names. If you have `template <typename T>` and call `MACRO(T)`, you get `T` as text and nothing else. Only macros can possibly extend macros.

Comment: @Useless I could, but the point of this is to get rid of macroses, keep them away and don't deal with them directly.

Comment: Nothing that happens in translation phase 8 can possibly affect what the preprocessor did in phase 4: it's too late. The only alternative to a macro here is to use something even earlier: codegen.

Comment: `GetMacroValue##name` returns `#name`, so `template <StringLiteral S> auto MacroWrapper<s>::getValue() { return S; }` would do the job, no?

Comment: @Jarod42 That was a simplified example. The real ones are much more complicated: https://github.com/alliedmodders/metamod-source/blob/master/core/sourcehook/sourcehook.h

Comment: file has 4928 lines, and a lot of MACRO, which one is the correct one?